# Use function on column and then use another function on output of new column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I've been trying to figure out a way that I can use a function on a column to get a certain output back (within a column) and then additionally use another function on the column that I previously got output from in another column.  Sounds confusing right?  Let me show you an example to make it a little bit easier to understand.

```
SELECT PAGE, substr(PAGE, 1, instr(PAGE, ';', -1) - 1) PAGE2, substr(PAGE2, instr(PAGE2, '/', -1)+1) PAGE_NEW
FROM 
    SNETP001.INGACCESS_VIEWS INGACCESS_VIEWS,
     SNETP001.INGACCESS_PAGEID INGACCESS_PAGEID
```

PAGE is the originating column from the table
PAGE2 is the column created using the SUBSTR and nested INSTR function
PAGE_NEW is the additional column that I wanted to run on PAGE2 column.

Any thoughts on this?  I can try to provide additional information if needed.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using a subquery as :

```
Select PAGE, PAGE2, substr(PAGE2, instr(PAGE2, '/', -1)+1) PAGE_NEW
 FROM
 ( SELECT PAGE, substr(PAGE, 1, instr(PAGE, ';', -1) - 1) PAGE2
  FROM 
   SNETP001.INGACCESS_VIEWS INGACCESS_VIEWS,
   SNETP001.INGACCESS_PAGEID INGACCESS_PAGEID)
```

Or you can write the substr function twice on the PAGE column as below:

```
   SELECT PAGE, substr(PAGE, 1, instr(PAGE, ';', -1) - 1) PAGE2, 
   substr(substr(PAGE,   1, instr(PAGE, ';', -1) - 1),
          instr(substr(PAGE, 1, instr(PAGE, ';', -1) - 1), '/', -1)+1)  PAGE_NEW
   FROM 
     SNETP001.INGACCESS_VIEWS INGACCESS_VIEWS,
     SNETP001.INGACCESS_PAGEID INGACCESS_PAGEID
```

Hope i haven't missed something here in your req.

Vishad